# Build jar from command line including jnetpcap

Tags: java, jnetpcap

I have written a Programm that uses JnetPcap but dont know how to build a jarfile from my Project. its not an IDE Project, i had compiled everything from command line. my Folder structure is as followed

```
jnetpcap.dll
jnetpcap.jar
manifest.mf
Program$1.class
Program$2.class
Program$3.class
Program$4.class
Program.class
Program.java
Request.class
```

In the manifest.mf

```
Main-Class: Program
Class-Path: jnetpcap.jar
```

When i try to build it by issuing

```
jar cfm Program.jar manifest.mf *.class *.dll
```

i get no Errors and its build, but i cant start my jarfile Program.jar

Comment: How are you loading the dll? Just for a test try to copy the dll in the same directory as the jar and try to start it again

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
jar cvfm Program.jar manifest.txt *.class *.dll
```

Refer this :
http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html

Comment: thank you i had. when i try to start there popup 2 Windows. The first says "A JNI Error has occured, please check your installation" and the second says "A Java Exception has occured". when i start it normaly by calling entry class its starting. maybe i have to include jnetpcap.jar in the command?

Comment: yes. If this is correct answer for your question pls mark as correct this answer.